# Ooops. How can I re-install the Mac App Store?

Tags: macos, mac-appstore

I'm running Mac OS X version 10.7.2.

There's this app called app-zapper. It helps to remove the library and cache files from apps when you want to get rid of an app by "zapping" it. I needed to shave some space. I'm using Pixelmator now instead of Photoshop, so I tried to zap my Adobe folder but instead my App Store app got zapped. I didn't realize it till my trash was emptied. The rest writes itself.

I've tried reinstalling 10.7.2, extracting the App Store.app file from 10.7.2 package (it's incomplete) and re-downloading the snow leopard extracted one (don't work on lion).

How can I re-install the app store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my copy, hope it helps.

http://www.ilorentz.org/~gio/public/App%20Store.zip

PS: I'm going to remove it next week, so be quick!

Comment: Success!!! Thx very much.

Comment: I deleted it, so now be good and don't erase it again :D

Comment: It's not wise to accept sweets from strangers on the internet. (With all respect to Gio.)

Answer (score 4):

Many options are available to you:

- Restore it from your backup
- Copy it from another Mac running 10.7.2
- Download and apply the current combo updater (often they contain entire programs, but it's not a guaranteed thing)
- Reinstall Lion and upgrade to 10.7.2 - if your Lion install is lower than 10.7.2 try not to run programs until they are all patched up to the same version as your existing software.

Comment: Another alternative would be to use something like Pacifist and pull it directly from the InstallESD.dmg and then run the 10.7.2 combo update afterwards.

Comment: I tried all those things except for the backup and the reinstall of Lion. Nothing helped. I'm going to try Geo's, and if that doesn't work, the re-install. (eeekkk)